# BirthDate on Registration Page, Eclipse

Tags: android, cordova, fullcalendar

How can I add a simple calendar that when a user clicks on the "Birthdate field" it will direct to another page or a pop-up box that has a calendar and so the user can select the date of his/her birth? I am developing an android application in eclipse with PhoneGap 1.4.1, Many Thank you guys.

Comment: you have to make adapter that will open the popup of calender..i have some code that i attached plz see that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I did:

Create a Calendar instance for default value:

```
//class level variables
private int mYear;
private int mMonth;
private int mDay;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;

//inside onCreate
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)-20;
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); //Default DOB is (today - 20) years

  //date picker things
    mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    mYear = year;
                    mMonth = monthOfYear;
                    mDay = dayOfMonth;
                    updateDisplay();
                }
    };
```

A function to update Date of Birth EditText field:

```
private void updateDisplay() {
    et_dob.setText(new StringBuilder().append(mMonth+1).append("/").append(mDay).append("/").append(mYear).append(" "));
    //month is 0 based so 1 is added in mMonth;
}
```

onClickListener on et_dob

```
showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID); //DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
```

Then override onCreateDialog in your activity:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    mDateSetListener,
                    mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    }
    return null;        
}
```

You should see something like this when you click on EditText et_dob.

[image: DatePicker]

Comment: you can directly use DatePicker, no need to create an array of months and days. the moment et_dob gets focus you will see this date picker dialog box. user can select the date and click on set to dismiss the dialog and show it on the EditText.

Comment: oops I didn't see the phonegap part. Still I think this will work.

Comment: where should I put this code anyway? :D, sorry this is my first time building an app. but I appreciate your answer here. :D,

Comment: I have written that in comments... the first five lines of code is declaration (inside activity but outside and before onCreate). Next Final Calendar things inside onCreate. updateDisplay function outside activity (just like we do in java). Add an onCLickListener to DOB editText. in the onclick event call showDialog. Then Override onCreateDialog and copy the code. Just to be clear... is the image above what you wanted ? AND do you have any more doubts ?

Answer (score 2):

Here Is the xml File

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:paddingLeft="12dp"
    android:paddingRight="12dp" android:paddingTop="30dp">

    <com.wheel.WheelView android:id="@+id/day"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="46dp" />
    <com.wheel.WheelView android:id="@+id/month"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="100dp" />
    <com.wheel.WheelView android:id="@+id/year"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Set"
    android:onClick="setclick">
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.timesoft;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.wheel.ArrayWheelAdapter;
import com.wheel.NumericWheelAdapter;
import com.wheel.OnWheelChangedListener;
import com.wheel.WheelView;

public class Popup_Date extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
WheelView month;
WheelView year;
WheelView day;

String months[];

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.popup_date);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();     

    month = (WheelView) findViewById(R.id.month);
    year = (WheelView) findViewById(R.id.year);
    day = (WheelView) findViewById(R.id.day);

    OnWheelChangedListener listener = new OnWheelChangedListener() {
        public void onChanged(WheelView wheel, int oldValue, int newValue) {
            updateDays(year, month, day);
        }
        };

    // month
    int curMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
     months= new String[] { "January", "February", "March",
            "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
            "October", "November", "December" };
    month.setViewAdapter(new DateArrayAdapter(this, months, curMonth));
    month.setCurrentItem(curMonth);
    month.addChangingListener(listener);

    // year
    int curYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    year.setViewAdapter(new DateNumericAdapter(this, curYear-10, curYear + 10,0));
    year.setCurrentItem(curYear);
    year.addChangingListener(listener);

    // day
    updateDays(year, month, day);
    day.setCurrentItem(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)-1);
}
public void setclick(View v) {
    if(GlobalData.forwhich.equals("1"))
    {
    GlobalData.leave_date_from = String.valueOf(year.getCurrentItem()+2001) + "-"
            + month.getCurrentItem() + "-"
            + String.valueOf(day.getCurrentItem()+1);
    }
    else if(GlobalData.forwhich.equals("2"))
    {
        GlobalData.leave_date_to = String.valueOf(year.getCurrentItem()+2001) + "-"
        + month.getCurrentItem() + "-"
        + String.valueOf(day.getCurrentItem()+1);
    }
    else
    {
        GlobalData.selected_date = String.valueOf(year.getCurrentItem()+2001) + "-"
        + months[month.getCurrentItem()] + "-"
        + String.valueOf(day.getCurrentItem()+1);
    }
    finish();
}
/**
 * Updates day wheel. Sets max days according to selected month and year
 */
void updateDays(WheelView year, WheelView month, WheelView day) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + year.getCurrentItem());
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month.getCurrentItem());

    int maxDays = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    day.setViewAdapter(new DateNumericAdapter(this, 1, maxDays, calendar
            .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - 1));
    int curDay = Math.min(maxDays, day.getCurrentItem() + 1);
    day.setCurrentItem(curDay - 1, true);

    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day.getCurrentItem() + 1);
    Log.i("date :",
            new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(calendar.getTime()));
}

/**
 * Adapter for numeric wheels. Highlights the current value.
 */
private class DateNumericAdapter extends NumericWheelAdapter {
    // Index of current item
    int currentItem;
    // Index of item to be highlighted
    int currentValue;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public DateNumericAdapter(Context context, int minValue, int maxValue,
            int current) {
        super(context, minValue, maxValue);
        this.currentValue = current;
        setTextSize(16);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureTextView(TextView view) {
        super.configureTextView(view);
        if (currentItem == currentValue) {
            view.setTextColor(0xFF0000F0);
        }
        view.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);
    }

    @Override
    public View getItem(int index, View cachedView, ViewGroup parent) {
        currentItem = index;
        return super.getItem(index, cachedView, parent);
    }
}

/**
 * Adapter for string based wheel. Highlights the current value.
 */
private class DateArrayAdapter extends ArrayWheelAdapter<String> {
    // Index of current item
    int currentItem;
    // Index of item to be highlighted
    int currentValue;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public DateArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] items, int current) {
        super(context, items);
        this.currentValue = current;
        setTextSize(16);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureTextView(TextView view) {
        super.configureTextView(view);
        if (currentItem == currentValue) {
            view.setTextColor(0xFF0000F0);
        }
        view.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);
    }

    @Override
    public View getItem(int index, View cachedView, ViewGroup parent) {
        currentItem = index;
        return super.getItem(index, cachedView, parent);
    }
}
```

}